# Google spreadsheet, how to protect Cell?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I create excel file and proteced some field in this file. In Office excel all fine my some cell locked for edit, begin I upload my excel file in google drive with convert - true (Whether to convert this file to the corresponding Google Docs format. (Default: false)) But in google spread sheet I can edit locked cell, how to locked in google spread sheet some cell ?

create excel file

```
    $phpExcel = new \PHPExcel();
    $ews = $phpExcel->getSheet(0);
    $ews->setTitle(Reports::LIST_AOG);
    $ews->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
    $ews
        ->getStyle('E6:F36')
        ->getProtection()->setLocked(
            \PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED
        );
```

and now I can edit only E6:F36 cell in my file in computer, then upload in google drive

```
$insertArray = [
        'mimeType' => $fileUpload->getMimeType(),
        'uploadType' => 'media',
        'data' => file_get_contents($fileUpload),
        'convert' => true
    ];

    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client->getGoogleClient());
    $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

    $file->setTitle($nameFile);
    $file->setMimeType($fileUpload->getMimeType());

    try {
        $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, $insertArray);
        $spreadsheetId = $createdFile->getId();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $view = $this->view((array)GoogleDriveController::ERROR_OCCURRED . $e->getMessage(), 400);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```

I fing for google spreadsheet api bundle `asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client` but not find how to protected

```
    $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($arrayAccessTokenClient['access_token']);
    ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

    $spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService();

    $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetById($spreadsheetId);
    $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
    $cellFeed = $worksheet->getCellFeed();

    $cellFeed->editCell(1, 1, 'developer');
    $cellFeed->editCell(1, 2, 'hors');
    $cellFeed->editCell(10, 2, 'sum');
```

or how to protected cell with `asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client` ?

and In google spread sheet I can any edit any cell (((( Who knows hot to protected cell in google spreat sheet ?

**UPDATE**

I read [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/ranges) and try create request, this I have

```
    $arrayAccessTokenClient = json_decode($client->getGoogleClient()->getAccessToken(), true);

    $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($arrayAccessTokenClient['access_token']);
    ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

    $spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService();

    $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetById($spreadsheetId);
    $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
    $worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle(Reports::LIST_AOG);


        $addProtectedRange['addProtectedRange'] = [
        'protectedRange' => [
            'range' => [
                'sheetId' => $worksheet->getGid(),
                'startRowIndex' => 3,
                'endRowIndex' => 4,
                'startColumnIndex' => 0,
                'endColumnIndex' => 5,
            ],
            'description' => "Protecting total row",
            'warningOnly' => true
        ]
    ];
    $guzzle = new Client();
    $putTeam = $guzzle
        ->post('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'.$spreadsheetId.':batchUpdate?key='.$arrayAccessTokenClient['access_token'],
            [],
            json_encode($addProtectedRange)
        )
        ->send()
        ->getBody(true);
    $answer = json_decode($putTeam, true);
```

But have

```
Client error response
[status code] 401
[reason phrase] Unauthorized
[url]  https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1M_NFvKMZ7Rzbj9ww86AJRMto1UesIy71840r2sxbD5Y:batchUpdate?key=myAccessToken
```

Early I have Google Api Clien with access token and I can change cell and update with google spread sheet and work fine but `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'.$spreadsheetId.':batchUpdate?key='.$arrayAccessTokenClient['access_token'],`

return 401 and I not understand why and how to correct. Help

Answer (score 0):

I think google spreadsheets allow the editing of protected MSExcel sheets the moment they become Google docs. The rules for MSExcel doesn't always apply to Google Sheets. Reading from [Adding Named or Protected Ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/ranges):

> The following spreadsheets.batchUpdate request contains two request
>   objects. The first gives the range A1:E3 the name "Counts". The second
>   provides a warning-level protection to the range A4:E4. **This level
>   protection still allows cells within the range to be edited, but
>   prompts a warning prior to making the change**.

This [thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73252/protected-excel-sheet-is-unprotected-without-permission-in-google-spreadsheet/73255) also shares the same view.

However, if it's a google spreadsheet file you want to protect, check [this guide](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/144687?hl=en).

Comment: Let's start with this. 'sheetId' is not 'spreadsheetId'. sheetId is the number following 'gid' like gid=1234567 in your URL. In this instance, 1234567 is the sheetId

Comment: Update question. I replace to `$worksheet->getGid()` But still have 410 Unauthorized

Comment: why Unauthorized, if with this `$arrayAccessTokenClient['access_token']` I edit cell and every this all fine

Comment: since you're using Sheets API, it must be enabled

Comment: in my app Sheets API enabled, and with `asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client` I can edit cell in spreadsheet and every thins fine

Comment: go to oauth playground get yourself an oauth token from sheetsv4, allow permission , generate token and try to use that as access_token. if it works, then u know where the problem is.

Comment: I try in Playgriund, and all good, I see request `Authorization: Bearer ya29.Ci80AxlHEzPA0nAfTW6aiM5ztjvX7_E2xIlI977HxX2bmJwhfB2df8ZeSACzgM_5pQ` maybe this problem, because I add `?key=myAccessToken` I try this and let you know

Comment: yes, use that as your 'access_token' .it only has 1 hr lifecycle. if it works, then you current access_token handling is the problem.

Comment: Yes, when I add in headers `Authorization: Bearer ya29.Ci80AxlHEzPA0nAfTW6aiM5ztjvX7_E2xIlI977HxX2bmJwhfB2df8ZeSACzgM_5pQ` I have protected cell in google spread sheet. But uwer with role writer can edit this cell, now only add window for atention this is protected range, but I need protected for edit for all user

Answer (score 0):

I read [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/ranges) and

```
        $addProtectedRange['requests'] = [
        'addProtectedRange' => [
            'protectedRange' => [
                'range' => [
                    'sheetId' => $worksheetGid,
                    'startRowIndex' => $startRowIndex,
                    'endRowIndex' => $endRowIndex,
                    'startColumnIndex' => $startColumnIndex,
                    'endColumnIndex' => $endColumnIndex,
                ],
                'description' => "Protecting total row",
                'warningOnly' => false,
                'editors' => [
                    'users' => [
                        "shuba.ivan.vikt@gmail.com"
                    ]
]
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

This `file_get_contents` variant, because Guzzle not returned json response from google, like this:

```
{
 "protectedRangeId": number,
 "range": {
   object(GridRange)
 },
 "namedRangeId": string,
 "description": string,
 "warningOnly": boolean,
 "requestingUserCanEdit": boolean,
 "unprotectedRanges": [
   {
     object(GridRange)
   }
 ],
  "editors": {
   object(Editors)
 },
}
```

I create new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742294/how-get-json-respone-from-guzzle-post-protected-google-spread-sheet?noredirect=1#comment64859502_38742294) for this for Guzzle reasponse

This is variant for update protected edit cell

```
    $addProtectedRangeJson = json_encode($addProtectedRange);
    $url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' . $spreadsheetId . ':batchUpdate';
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Authorization: Bearer $arrayAccessTokenClient\r\n",
            'content' => $addProtectedRangeJson
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
    $answer = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    $addProtectedRangeUpdate['requests'] = [
        'updateProtectedRange' => [
            'protectedRange' => [
                'protectedRangeId' => $protectedRangeId,
                'warningOnly' => false,
                'editors' => [
                    'users' => [
                        "shuba.ivan.vikt@gmail.com"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'fields' => "namedRangeId,warningOnly,editors"
        ]
    ];
    $addProtectedRangeUpdateJson = json_encode($addProtectedRangeUpdate);
    $optsUpdate = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Authorization: Bearer $arrayAccessTokenClient\r\n",
            'content' => $addProtectedRangeUpdateJson
        )
    );

    $contextUpdate = stream_context_create($optsUpdate);
    $responseUpdate = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $contextUpdate);
    $answerUpdate = json_decode($responseUpdate, TRUE);
```

and this is Guzzle, but Guzzle without google json response this is bad I wait maybe who know what is it problem, because standard php function `file_get_contents` work very well and I have json google response. But without response this variant work normal, cell protected in spread sheet

```
    $guzzle = new Client();

    $postCell = $guzzle
        ->post('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' . $spreadsheetId . ':batchUpdate',
            [],
            $addProtectedRangeJson
        )
        ->addHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $arrayAccessTokenClient)
        ->addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ;
    $postCell
        ->send()
        ->getBody(true)
    ;
    $contents = (string) $postCell->getBody();// get body that I post -> my request, not response 
    $contents = $postCell->getBody()->getContents();// not find getContents, ask me did you mean to call getContentMd5
    $answer = json_decode($postCell->getResponse()->getBody(), true);
```